# ACL On Linux like Windows Permissions

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, filesystems, acl

Is there something for Linux where you have more advanced controls for linux permissions on users and groups like Windows. Is that what SeLinux is about?

Answer (score 3):

Almost all Unix-like systems support ACLs; on Linux, the [POSIX ACL](http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) format is used. FreeBSD supports both POSIX and NFSv4 style ACLs (there are periodic attempts to add [NFSv4 ACLs](http://users.suse.com/~agruen/nfs4acl/) to Linux as well).

The POSIX ACL format is mostly just an extension to allow specifying the read/write/execute permissions for several users:

```
$ setfacl -m u::rw,u:httpd:r,g::- ssl.key

$ getfacl ssl.key
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:openldap:r--
user:httpd:r--
user:postfix:r--
group::---
mask::r--
other::---
```

Inheritance is done using "default ACLs":

```
$ getfacl /var/log/journal/
# owner: root
# group: systemd-journal
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:adm:r-x
default:group:wheel:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::r-x

$ touch /var/log/journal/test
$ getfacl /var/log/journal/test
# owner: root
# group: systemd-journal
user::rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
group:adm:r-x       #effective:r--
group:wheel:r-x     #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

---

On the other hand, the NFSv4 ACL format would be very similar to that of Windows & NTFS – slightly different principal names (using NFSv4-style user@domain rather than Windows SIDs or DOMAIN\name), but almost identical permission flags.

---

Both ACLs and basic Unix permissions are a "discretionary access control" tool – they're generally set by the object's owner; if you create a file, you can make it readable to anyone. SELinux, meanwhile, is an implementation of [*mandatory* access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) – all SELinux rules are written by the system administrator and cannot be changed by users, even for files they have created. Other such systems are AppArmor, SMACK; Windows Vista has a very basic scheme called [Mandatory Integrity Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Integrity_Control).